# Hibernate Tools. JPA 2.0 without EJB

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, annotations

Hibernate Tools has 2 diffeent configurations regarding this topic.

You got the Console config with the options Hibernate 3.5/3.6/4.0 plus
and Core / (Hibernate) Annotations / JPA Annotations

and later in launch code generator menu we already can select in exporters: Java 5+ and EJB options.

But the behaviour seeems a bit inconsistent for me, as marking JPA annotations without EJB option erases any annotation. So is there any way to make Hibenrate generate non-EJB JPA annotations code (DAO+POJOS)?

THe thing is I don't want to get an injected EntityManager, and I am not using any EJB container but SDK. I am wondering whther there is an smart code generation in that case